# How to update response from external api in DRF

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am dealing with an assignment, which needs to request a third party API and take a few bites of the response and update their keys and render as DRF response.

Can this be achieved via serializers?

Here what I am doing.

```
response = BooksService().get_books()
transformed_data = self.transform_data(response)
return Response(transformed_data)

def transform_data(response):
    data = response.json()    
    required_data = {
        key_i_need_1 = data.get(KeyINeed1)
        key_i_need_2 = data.get(KeyINeed2)
        ...
    }
    return required_data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try doing something like this.

Serializer will respect only the fields which are defined in it, others it'll ignore.

```
class ResponseSerializer(Serializer):
    required_field1 = serializers.FieldType()
    required_field2 = serializers.FieldType()
    required_field3 = serializers.FieldType()
    required_field4 = serializers.FieldType()
    required_field5 = serializers.FieldType()

    class Meta:
        fields = (required_field1, required_field2, required_field3, required_field4, required_field5)


def view():
    response = requests.get(external_api).json()
    modified_response = ResponseSerializer(data=response)
    return Response(modified_response.data)
```